# What's the easiest way to generate an HTML file?

Tags: c#, html, .net, console-application

I'm working on a console application that's supposed to spit out an html document that contains a table and maybe some javascript.

I thought about writing the html by hand:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine("<html>");
streamWriter.WriteLine("<body>");
streamWriter.WriteLine(GetHtmlTable());
streamWriter.WriteLine("</body>");
streamWriter.WriteLine("</html>");
```

... but was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it. Something along these lines:

```
Page page = new Page();
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.DataSource = GetDataTable();
gridView.DataBind();

page.Controls.Add(gridView);
page.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
htmlWriter.Flush();
```

Assuming that I'm on the right track, what's the proper way to build the rest of the html document (ie: html, head, title, body elements) using the `System.Web.UI.Page` class? Do I need to use literal controls?

Comment: You might find `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper` to be useful.

Comment: John can you clarify what where you are building this application is it `Console App` or a `Web App`

Comment: You're on the right track with the second example. I did it like this before (Don't have the code with me atm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do a lot of automated HTML page generation.  I like to create an HTML page template with custom tags where to insert the dynamic controls, data, or literals.   I then read template file into a string and replace the custom tag with the generated HTML like you are doing above and write the HTML file back out of the string.  This saves me the time of creating all the tedious support HTML for the design template, css, and supporting JS.

Template File Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <CUSTOMHEAD />
    </head>
    <body>
        <CUSTOMDATAGRID />
    </body>
</html>
```

Create HTML From Template File loaded into string Example

```
    private void GenerateHTML(string TemplateFile, string OutputFileName)
    {

        string strTemplate = TemplateFile;
        string strHTMLPage = "";
        string strCurrentTag = "";

        int intStartIndex = 0;
        int intEndIndex = 0;


        while (strTemplate.IndexOf("<CUSTOM", intEndIndex) > -1)
        {
            intStartIndex = strTemplate.IndexOf("<CUSTOM", intEndIndex);

            strHTMLPage += strTemplate.Substring(intEndIndex, 
                                                 intStartIndex - intEndIndex);

            strCurrentTag = strTemplate.Substring(intStartIndex,
                 strTemplate.IndexOf("/>", intStartIndex) + 6 - intStartIndex);
            strCurrentTag = strCurrentTag.ToUpper();

            switch (strCurrentTag)
            {
                case "<CUSTOMHEAD />":
                    strHTMLPage += GenerateHeadJavascript();
                    break;

                case "<CUSTOMDATAGRID />":
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    GridView.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));
                    strHTMLPage += sw.ToString();
                    sw.Close();
                    break;

                case "<CUSTOMANYOTHERTAGSYOUMAKE />":
                    //strHTMLPage += YourControlsRenderedAsString();
                    break;

            }
            intEndIndex = strTemplate.IndexOf("/>", intStartIndex) + 2;
        }

        strHTMLPage += strTemplate.Substring(intEndIndex);

        try
        {
            StreamWriter swHTMLPage = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
                                                OutputFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8);
            swHTMLPage.Write(strHTMLPage);
            swHTMLPage.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // AppendLog("Write File Failed: " + OutputFileName + " - " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be a good idea for you to use a templating system to decouple your presentation and business logic.

Take a look at Razor Generator which allows the use of CSHTML templates within non ASP.NET applications.

http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/